# CS50 pset1 Greedy not working

Tags: c, cs50

Like others here, I am trying to make a program called greedy that will tell me the least amount of coins that I have to give someone as change for a given amount of money. I made this but it gives me the wrong amount of coins and I don't know why :(

```
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include <cs50.h>
 #include <math.h>

 int main(void)

 {
     float given_amount;
     int cent_count;
     int coin_count = 0; 

     do
     {
        printf("What is the amount of change I owe you?\n");
        given_amount = GetFloat();
     }
     while (given_amount < 0);

     cent_count = (int)round(given_amount * 100);

     while (cent_count > 25)
     {
         coin_count++;
         cent_count -= 25;
     }
     while (cent_count > 10)
     {
         coin_count++;
         cent_count -= 10;
     }
     while (cent_count >= 1)
     {
         coin_count++;
         cent_count -= 1;
     }

     printf("Take these %d coins\n", coin_count);

 }
```

If I tell the program I need to give back `25 cents` the program tells me I have to give the person `7 coins`, but it should just tell me I have to give him `one coin... a quarter`.

Comment: If i tell the program i need to give back 25 cents the program tells me I have to give the person 7 coins, but it should just tell me I have to give him one coin... a quarter.

Comment: No matter the number of cent you deduce, you keep increasing `coin_count` whithout making a distinction between the value of the coins, C variables don't have a unit, you must create a different variable for each type of coin.

Comment: But in the end each coin (not mattering what size it is) is one coin. so shoudldn't  it not matter if I only have one counter counting all the coins? Like not making a distinction between pennies and quarters so forth?

Comment: `while (cent_count > 25)` --> `while (cent_count >= 25)` and `while (cent_count > 10)` --> `while (cent_count >= 10)`

Comment: Ok, I think I misunderstood your problem, forget my comment.

Comment: ok ok thanks anyway ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your first 2 loops don't take care of value `25` and `10`.

In fact your algorithm is giving you 7, that is: `2 coins` of `10 cent`, and `5 coins` of `1 cent`.

You must check for them, so:

```
 while (cent_count >= 25)
 {
     coin_count++;
     cent_count -= 25;
 }
 while (cent_count >= 10)
 {
     coin_count++;
     cent_count -= 10;
 }
```

Comment: ok ok yeah thanks I didn't see that ;) but it still spits out wrong answers :/ Like someof them are correct but some are wrong

Comment: like if i say the person gave 20 dollars it gives the right answer of saying i have to give the person 80 coins (80 quarters). But if I put a more complex one like saying the person need 41 cents change the program says I have to give them 8 coins (when the answer should be 4 coins)

Comment: So your code is supposed to count the minimum number of coins that can express the input value. If so your code is quite far away from the goal.... Actually is giving the number of coins with priority to 25 cent, then evaluate 10 cent and at the end checks for 1 cent. So the 8 coins is the correct answer of your actual algorithm `41` = `25x1` + `10x1` + `1x6`

Comment: Oh i'm sorry it was working after that fix... just that the thing that was checking the answers wanted them written differently

Comment: yeah yeah I was just checking and saw that 8 was the actual answer I'm sorry I didn't see that thanks a lot :)

Comment: But so are you saying that the code is not correct? Like I am actually calculating something different?

Comment: No. I'm saying that the algorithm is working correctly giving you 8. But if your goal is to have the minum number of coins needed the code is wrong. I mean if your aim is to have `5` as answer to `41` (`10x4` + `1x1`) this is not the way you can achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's my code:

```
#include <cs50.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int main(void)
{
float input = -1.00;
int n = 0;
int c = 0;

printf("O hai! How much change is owed?: ");
do
{
input = GetFloat();
if(input < 0)
printf("Positive number, please!: ");
}
while (input < 0);
c = roundf(input * 100);

while(c >= 25)
{ 
    c = c - 25;
    n++;
}
while (c >= 10)
{
    c = c - 10;
    n++;
}
while (c >= 5)
{
    c = c - 5;
    n++;
}
n = n + c;

printf("%i\n", n);
}
```